# I can't get selenium (java) to click the search bar in neither facebook or instagram

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm fooling around with selenium to try to make my account search for a specific hashtag, but I'm stuck on why I can't get it to push the search button.

instagram's buttons seems to be made with SVG, and this makes it harder for me to get it to work and with facebook it is just not accepting my approach, which is working with the login.

Here is my example with instagram at the moment.

```
// Find the SVG element using XPath
WebElement svgElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//svg[@aria-label='Search']"));

// Create an instance of the Actions class
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

// Move to the SVG element and click it
actions.moveToElement(svgElement).click().build().perform();
```

I have also tried this:

```
// Find the SVG element using XPath
WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[local-name()='svg' and @aria-label='Search']/*[localname()='path']"));
// clicking on SVG element
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(search).click().build().perform();
```

Here is the source for instagram:

```
<div class="x9f619 x3nfvp2 xr9ek0c xjpr12u xo237n4 x6pnmvc x7nr27j x12dmmrz xz9dl7a xn6708d xsag5q8 x1ye3gou x1l895ks x159b3zp xdoji71 x1dejxi8 x9k3k5o xs3sg5q x11hdxyr x12ldp4w x1wj20lx x1dn74xm xif99yt x172qv1o x10djquj x1lhsz42 xzauu7c x1z11no5 xjy5m1g x1mnwbp6 x4pb5v6">
  <div>
    <div class="x9f619 xjbqb8w x78zum5 x168nmei x13lgxp2 x5pf9jr xo71vjh x1n2onr6 x1plvlek xryxfnj x1c4vz4f x2lah0s xdt5ytf xqjyukv x1qjc9v5 x1oa3qoh x1nhvcw1">
      <div class="x9f619 xxk0z11 xvy4d1p x11xpdln xii2z7h x19c4wfv">
        <svg aria-label="Search" class="_ab6-" color="rgb(245, 245, 245)" fill="rgb(245, 245, 245)" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
          <path d="M19 10.5A8.5 8.5 0 1 1 10.5 2a8.5 8.5 0 0 1 8.5 8.5Z" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path>
          <line fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke- linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" x1="16.511" x2="22" y1="16.511" y2="22"></line>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="x6s0dn4 x9f619 xxk0z11 x6ikm8r xeq5yr9 x1s85apg x1swvt13 xzzcqpx" style="opacity: 1;">
    <div style="width: 100%;">
      <div class="_aacl _aacp _aacu _aacx _aada">Search</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my current code for facebook:

```
WebElement searchbar = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@dir='ltr']")));
searchbar.click();
searchbar.sendKeys("hello");
```

Here is the sourcecode from facebook:

```
<input dir="ltr" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Søg på Facebook" role="combobox" placeholder="Søg på Facebook" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" aria-invalid="false" class="x1i10hfl xggy1nq x1s07b3s x1kdt53j x1yc453h xhb22t3 xb5gni xcj1dhv x2s2ed0 xq33zhf xjyslct xjbqb8w x6umtig x1b1mbwd xaqea5y xav7gou xnwf7zb x40j3uw x1s7lred x15gyhx8 x9f619 xzsf02u xdl72j9 x1iyjqo2 xs83m0k xjb2p0i x6prxxf xeuugli x1a2a7pz x1n2onr6 x15h3p50 xm7lytj x1sxyh0 xdvlbce xurb0ha x1vqgdyp xo6swyp x1ad04t7 x1glnyev x1ix68h3 x19gujb8" type="search" value="" aria-controls="jsc_c_2t">
```

Comment: We can't help you with a locator without the HTML of the element you are trying to click. Edit the question and post the relevant HTML as text, properly formatted and we will try to help you.

Comment: You are right, sorry.

Comment: Why is this such a hard task? 
When I'm searching the internet for answers, none of the solutions are working. Has the two sites put something on to make it harder for selenium to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Instagram, you need a wait before clicking the SVG because it takes the page a moment to load. Here's working code.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/twitter/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("svg[aria-label='Search']"))).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[aria-label='Search input']")).sendKeys("Test\n");

driver.quit();
```

Comment: Ahh TY - I did try to put in some sleep and/or wait, but it didn't help I can see you also changed it to .elementToBeClickable and it is working perfecktly on instagram!

Now I'm just wondering why the same approach can't be used on Facebook? Do you know the technical reason for this, thanks in advance.